# Multiple keys problems and auto increment

Tags: mysql

I'm starting to get crazy, I want to create this table but doesn't let me add the auto increment, I have done this before but in this case is not working... I have try this way..

```
CREATE TABLE cuentas(
     a enum("B","CC") default "CC", 
     b CHAR default 0, 
     c BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
     d enum("E","S"), fecha DATETIME, 
     e INT UNSIGNED,
     f INT UNSIGNED, 
     g INT UNSIGNED 
     (...) 
     PRIMARY KEY (a,b,c)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

this other way

```
CREATE TABLE _table (
     a enum("B","CC") default "CC", 
     b CHAR default 0, 
     c BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
     d enum("E","S"), fecha DATETIME, 
     e INT UNSIGNED,
     f INT UNSIGNED, 
     g INT UNSIGNED
     (...)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB

    ALTER TABLE _table DROP PRIMARY KEY;
    ALTER TABLE _table ADD PRIMARY KEY (a,b,c)';
```

It does create the multiple key but the `AUTO_INCREMENT` doesn't work at the execution...

---

**UPDATE 2**

The problem was that it wasn't MyISAM, Works perfectly like this. But, if you need transactions this will not be the answer.

```
CREATE TABLE cuentas(
     a enum("B","CC") default "CC", 
     b CHAR default 0,
     c BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
     d enum("E","S"),
     e INT UNSIGNED,
     f INT UNSIGNED, 
     g INT UNSIGNED 
     (...) 
     PRIMARY KEY (a,b,c)
     ) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

---

**UPDATE**

Found the solution, just change the order on the definition of the primary key to set the 'c' column at first.. like this.

```
CREATE TABLE cuentas(
     a enum("B","CC") default "CC", 
     b CHAR default 0,
     c BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
     d enum("E","S"), fecha DATETIME, 
     e INT UNSIGNED,
     f INT UNSIGNED, 
     g INT UNSIGNED 
     (...) 
     PRIMARY KEY (c,b,a)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: The auto_increment column has to be the primary key. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3467/mysql-why-is-auto-increment-limited-to-just-primary-keys

Comment: You can just create a unique index on `(a, b, c)`, it doesn't have to be the primary key.

Comment: @Barmar  Yeah i know that has to be primary key, but when the deal is that i need a b c to be primaries and c to be the auto-increment value...

Comment: Why do you need them to be primaries? What's the difference between making them primary and making them unique?

Comment: Are you trying to get `c` to increment within each group of `a` and `b`? That's only available with MyISAM, not InnoDB. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: I found the solution... Just change PRIMARY KEY (a,b,c) for PRIMARY KEY (c,a,b)   without changing the order of the columns and it works... not sure why... but works..

Comment: You should post it as an answer, then. And please give your CAPS LOCK key a rest.

Comment: Your solution cannot work in innodb. You must be mistaken

Comment: @Strawberry it works see  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/196c2/1/0

Comment: @Strawberry ok you were right! sorry about that, does create the table but doesn't have the function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this :

```
CREATE TABLE cuentas(
     a enum("B","CC") default "CC", 
     b CHAR default 0,
     c BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
     d enum("E","S"), fecha DATETIME, 
     e INT UNSIGNED,
     f INT UNSIGNED, 
     g INT UNSIGNED, 
     (...) 
     PRIMARY KEY (c),
     INDEX (a,b)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: I need the multiple primary key, cause the id will reset with any change of 'a' o 'b'. but it works with the solution...